# Apache poi save chart as png

Tags: java, image, charts, apache-poi

I am trying to extract chart as image from excel file using apache poi.

I got chart data from my workbook with code below

```
workbook.getSheetAt(0).createDrawingPatriarch().getCharts().get(0);
```

Somebody know how to save this chart as image?

Comment: You wrote how you got the chart but you didn't write how you've attempted to save it as an image.

Comment: I don't think this is supported in POI. You can easily save the pictures from an excel file but not charts. Im still looking. Looks like it is supported in Aspose or Jexcel. See this answer - https://groups.google.com/a/teamdev.com/d/msg/jexcel-forum/h4B6SG6YTXY/uiD-_D-PrXYJ

Comment: Nir, it is a problem:) I have no idea how to save it as image.

Comment: LittelePanda, thanks for help.
But aspose is not free... I am looking on Jexcel now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After week of trying, I found that there 2 ways:
1) use Aspose library
2) build chart independently using data from file, save this chart as you wish.

Comment: Did you happen to get the 2nd option working (if you even remember)?